# How do I find all IP addresses in Windows Phone 8.1 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-8

In the Windows Phone 8.1 emulators, there are several network interfaces defined, just as there were in Windows Phone 8. In Windows Phone 8, one could determine the IP address of all of the adapters with code similar to the following:

```
public static List<string> Find()
{
    List<string> ipAddresses = new List<string>();

    var hostnames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
    foreach (var hn in hostnames)
    {
        if (hn.IPInformation != null)
        {
            string ipAddress = hn.DisplayName;
            ipAddresses.Add(ipAddress);
        }
    }

    return ipAddress;
}
```

At first glance, this would appear to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506484/ip-address-in-windows-phone-8), or perhaps even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613284/how-can-i-find-the-ip-address-of-connected-network-in-windows-phone); however, the behavior appears to have changed in Windows Phone 8.1, such that the code provided in answers to those questions is no longer reliable. In my environment, the `IPInformation` property is `null` for two of the three network interfaces, and instead of having IP addresses as the name, they now have the values `Windows-Phone` and `Windows-Phone.local`. How can I find the IP addresses of all of the network adapter devices in the emulator for Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: Did you find a solution?